# Can a CISCO PIX tunnel SCTP traffic over an IPSEC tunnel

Tags: ipsec, cisco-pix, network-protocols

Can a cisco PIX 515e tunnel SCTP traffic over an IPSEC tunnel ?

I Know that the PIX doesn't support SCTP connection's but SCTP is still IP so i'm hoping the PIX has the capability to route SCTP over an IPSEC tunnel.

Also how would the access-list have to be specified for the encryption domain, would "ip" as the protocol catch SCTP traffic or should I specify SCTP explicitly by protocol number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have no problem tunneling the traffic; an IPSEC tunnel shouldn't care what the connection protocol is, as long as the transport is IP.

I'd recommend just setting up the specific protocol in the interface and crypto map ACLs, to make sure you're not getting unexpected results.

Comment: Yes it is up and working as expected now. I always assumed it "should" work but the below link (The top hit in google for 'cisco pix + sctp') suggested there may be issues: [link]https://supportforums.cisco.com/message/3050319?tstart=0